# How can partitioned index help if the range is needed to be given manually during index creation?

Tags: oracle, performance, indexing

Today I was reading about "Partitioned index" from this [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm#459659) for a performance tuning requirement.

The example that is given in the link reads like the following:

```
CREATE INDEX employees_global_part_idx ON employees(employee_id)
GLOBAL PARTITION BY RANGE(employee_id)
(PARTITION p1 VALUES LESS THAN(5000),
PARTITION p2 VALUES LESS THAN(MAXVALUE));
```

Till this all looks good except it is somewhat confusing to me that during definition of this index we are manually setting value of p1 as less than 5000

So for example, if the table has 12000 records, one partition has till 1 to 5000 records and the other one has 5000 to 12000 records which are unequal to each other. Also another hurdle in this approach is one can not make more partitions later on if intended. So this indexing approach with time will not be able to give a good performance advantage.

So is there any way overcome this problem in partitioned index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `employee_id` values are incremented when new records are created, you may want to use a `HASH` partitioned index instead of `RANGE` partitioned.

As per [Oracle Partitioning guide](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/VLDBG/GUID-A8991A7A-CEC0-4C6D-A886-17E0554BB3C6.htm):

> Hash partitioned global indexes can also limit the impact of index skew on monotonously increasing column values.

Your index creation query would then be:

```
CREATE INDEX employees_global_part_idx ON employees(employee_id) GLOBAL
  PARTITION BY HASH(employee_id)
  (PARTITION p1,
  PARTITION p2);
```

This lets Oracle take care of splitting the data evenly across the available partitions.

If you really want to use `RANGE` partitioned index, then every now and then you would need to maintain the index, by splitting the last partition and rebuilding the index.

Read also: [Global Partitioned Indexes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm#sthref70).

Comment: Hi, these values p1 and p2, what do they signify?

Comment: @Mistu4u These are the names of the partitions, as defined by you in the example you wrote in the question. You may use any text you want.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of partitioning Oracle provides three types of indexes:

- `Local Partitioned Indexes`: Each table partition has a corresponding index partition. I think this type is used (and useful) by majority.
- `Global Non-Partitioned Indexes`: The index has no partition and spans over entire table. For example, such indexes are required for unique keys where partition key is not part of the unique key.
- `Global Partitioned Indexes` (the type you refer in your question): You define partition rule of table independently from partition rule of the index.

Actually I cannot image any situation where a "Global Partitioned Indexes" really makes sense. They would be useful only for some very special, resp. exotic use-cases. Maybe when you have really huge amount of data and you have to distribute your index over different physical storages.

Comment: Global Hash Partitioned Index is used to relieve the index block contention in the right hand growth indexes.